# Slow query performance in Timescale DB (PostgreSQL verion 12)

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have a `client_requests` table with approximately 66k records. It has the following structure:

```
metrics=# \d+ client_requests;

      Column       |              Type              | Collation | Nullable |                   Default                   | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                | bigint                         |           | not null | nextval('client_requests_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 channel_id        | bigint                         |           | not null |                                             | plain    |              | 
 process_id        | uuid                           |           | not null |                                             | plain    |              | 
 route             | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                             | extended |              | 
 route_name        | character varying(255)         |           |          |                                             | extended |              | 
 duration          | double precision               |           | not null |                                             | plain    |              | 
 timestamp         | timestamp(0) without time zone |           | not null |                                             | plain    |              | 
 events            | jsonb                          |           |          |                                             | extended |              | 
 created_at        | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                             | plain    |              | 
 updated_at        | timestamp(0) without time zone |           |          |                                             | plain    |              | 

Indexes:
    "client_requests_timestamp_idx" btree ("timestamp" DESC)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "client_requests_channel_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (channel_id) REFERENCES channels(id)
    "client_requests_process_id_foreign" FOREIGN KEY (process_id) REFERENCES processes(id)
Triggers:
    ts_insert_blocker BEFORE INSERT ON client_requests FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION _timescaledb_internal.insert_blocker()
Child tables: _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_1_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_2_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_3_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_4_chunk,
              _timescaledb_internal._hyper_1_5_chunk

metrics=# select count(*) from client_requests;
 count 
-------
 66874
(1 row)
```

However, the following query takes 168ms to run, which is far longer than I would expect (I would expect single digit ms):

```
select
  time_bucket_gapfill('12 hours', timestamp, '2021-01-13 16:44:55', '2021-02-12 16:44:55') AS ts
 ,coalesce(ROUND(percentile_cont(0.5) within group (order by client_requests.duration)::numeric, 0), 0.00) as typical_response_time
 ,coalesce(ROUND(percentile_cont(0.95) within group (order by client_requests.duration)::numeric, 0), 0.00) as problem_response_time
from "client_requests"
where "timestamp" > NOW() - INTERVAL '30 days'
group by "ts"
order by "ts" asc;

(66 rows)
Time: 168.704 ms
```

An `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` query return the following:

```
Custom Scan (GapFill)  (cost=21746.41..23921.40 rows=38593 width=72) (actual time=152.965..199.968 rows=66 loops=1)
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=21746.41..23438.99 rows=38593 width=0) (actual time=152.957..199.864 rows=61 loops=1)
         Group Key: (time_bucket_gapfill('12:00:00'::interval, client_requests."timestamp"))
         ->  Sort  (cost=21746.41..21904.23 rows=63127 width=16) (actual time=152.703..163.472 rows=63101 loops=1)
               Sort Key: (time_bucket_gapfill('12:00:00'::interval, client_requests."timestamp"))
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 4494kB
               ->  Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on client_requests  (cost=0.00..16713.30 rows=63127 width=16) (actual time=3.251..120.119 rows=63101 loops=1)
                     Chunks excluded during startup: 0
                     ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_1_chunk  (cost=0.00..3239.92 rows=8866 width=16) (actual time=3.246..17.159 rows=8868 loops=1)
                           Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 3813
                     ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_2_chunk  (cost=0.00..4520.70 rows=17583 width=16) (actual time=0.020..26.201 rows=17583 loops=1)
                           Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                     ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_3_chunk  (cost=0.00..3606.74 rows=16214 width=16) (actual time=0.028..22.497 rows=16214 loops=1)
                           Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                     ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_4_chunk  (cost=0.00..3584.34 rows=14191 width=16) (actual time=0.024..21.248 rows=14191 loops=1)
                           Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
                     ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_1_5_chunk  (cost=0.00..1603.78 rows=6273 width=16) (actual time=0.021..9.236 rows=6245 loops=1)
                           Filter: ("timestamp" > (now() - '30 days'::interval))
 Planning Time: 2.128 ms
 Execution Time: 201.534 ms
(21 rows)

Time: 205.592 ms
```

With so few records in the table, its unclear to me why this query is performing so poorly.

Comment: Why would you use timescaledb on a table with 66k records?  A jet airplane is faster than walking, but not if you are only going from your kitchen to your living room.

Comment: No need to be snarky @jjanes. This is a test for a much larger rollout.

Answer (score 3):

You are sequentially scanning 5 partitions to get 63000 rows, gather the data, sort them and execute a TimescaleDB function. 200 milliseconds is not bad for that.